# How to generate propel ORM objects on virtual host with no include_path?

Tags: php, orm, build, propel, phing

I have a dev server with several virtual hosts on it.
Each one needs to be able to run the command:  propel-gen ./ creole
That script executes some php that reverse-engineers the database... 
BUT the php it executes needs to be included to do so.

There is no include_path set in the php.ini because it would be global to all virtual hosts.
I need the include_path to be unique for each vhost.

How can I have this work on the command-line? 
(note: htaccess won't work, because command-line doesn't go through apache).

Is there another way around this problem? 
Perhaps passing a command-line param to set an include path? 
Perhaps setting something in .bashrc? 
:(

P.S. - The script works fine on my mac, which has a hard-coded include path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running PHP from the command line, you can use the `-d` switch to define configuration options, that would normally be defined in `php.ini`

For more informations about what can be done when running PHP in CLI, you can take a look at [Using PHP from the command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

In your case, suppose you are running this, which only displays the current `include_path` :

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(get_include_path());'
```

Default output would be like this (on my machine, btw) :

```
string(20) ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

Now, using `-d` to override `include_path`, this way :

```
$ php -dinclude_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php:/var/my/directory/lib' -r 'var_dump(get_include_path());'
```

You're getting :

```
string(42) ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/var/my/directory/lib"
```

I admit, this is pretty boring/long to type, and you will sometimes forget the `-dblahblah` stuff...

So, you can define an alias, a bit like this :

```
$ alias myphp='php -dinclude_path=".:/usr/local/lib/php:/var/my/directory/lib"'
```

And now, if you are using `myphp` command instead of `php`, you don't need to specify the `include_path` anymore :

```
$ myphp -r 'var_dump(get_include_path());'
string(42) ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/var/my/directory/lib"
```

This won't persist between shell sessions... So you could put the `alias` command at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, so it's executed each time you log in :-)